# Is there a way to create a chat room in Slack using the URL?

Tags: slack-api, slack

Our team uses Slack. I would like our custom management app to automatically generate links to Slack chatrooms.

We can join rooms using the direct URL: [team].slack.com/messages/customRoom

Can we use a similar URL to create the room if non-existant? Something like: [team].slack.com/messages/customRoom/create

Comment: This is likely something you'd consult the documentation for.

Answer (score 0):

No, but the Slack API allows you to check if a channel exist and create a new one on demand. So you can get this functionality with a simple script, e.g. in PHP that uses the Slack API.

Here is the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.create) for the Slack API method to create a new channel.